# Access Secret Variables in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops

I'm using Team Services to store sensitive data instead of hardcoding it in my code.

Let's say I defined: `my_secret` as `name` and `12345` as `value` in Varibles

How do I access that variable in my code?

[image]

In the example above, how do I access `password` in my code?

There is a documentation [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables) but they don't mention it how to use the variable in the code.

Comment: Can you show us the code that stores the data?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: @ln9187 In the future, you may want to use an @ to make sure people see your message. Eric saw it because he was the only commenter on the post but that won't always be the case :) Note that if we are on the page a "this post has been edited" bar appears.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET 10-4!

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what these are for. Secret build variables are for "my build system uploads the built executable onto a server that requires a password", sort of thing.  You don't access the secrets from your code. You access them when the build system is doing custom build steps.

Comment: If what you're looking for is mechanisms for storing sensitive user data in encrypted format from a C# program, perhaps this is what you're looking for? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229741(v=vs.110).aspx  But really you should be doing a *threat model* that clearly describes the sensitive data, what it is being used for, who should and should not have access to it, what consequences are of a breach, what the lifetime of the data is, and so on.  Consider hiring an expert on threat modeling; this is not for security neophytes.

Comment: @ln9187 As Stuart said that you can use it directly by using $(password), do you success using it?

Answer (score 1):

Variables are usually passed to the build as environment variables. However secrets are not by default, you can use them explicitly in arguments to your tool like `MyTool.exe $(password)`.

Comment: That's how *non secret* build variables work. The question is about secret variables.  You don't want to be putting the database password into an environment variable where anyone can see it.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks for the correction, I've updated my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the secret variables during a build step (e.g. in your custom build task PowerShell based), usually you would use that secret variable as the input argument of a task, then use the [VSTS Task SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib)'s function [`Get-VstsInput`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/powershell/Docs/Commands.md#get-vstsinput) like it follows:

```
$pwd = Get-VstsInput -Name "Input_Name_In_Task.json_File"
```

Then you could convert it to a SecureString as follows

```
$securePwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pwd -AsPlainText -Force
```

and eventually use it in a new `System.Management.Automation.PSCredential` object.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "from the code". If you're, say, invoking a script, you can pass the secret in as an argument.

As an example, here's a build definition in JSON format.

```
{
  "build": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "continueOnError": false,
      "alwaysRun": false,
      "displayName": "PowerShell Script",
      "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
      "task": {
        "id": "e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1",
        "versionSpec": "1.*",
        "definitionType": "task"
      },
      "inputs": {
        "scriptType": "inlineScript",
        "scriptName": "",
        "arguments": "-Baz $(Baz)",
        "inlineScript": "param($Baz)\nWrite-Host \"1\" \nWrite-Host \"$($env:Foo)\" \nWrite-Host \"2\" \nWrite-Host \"$($env:Baz)\"\nWrite-Host $Baz",
        "workingFolder": "",
        "failOnStandardError": "true"
      }
    }
  ],
  "variables": {
    "foo": {
      "value": "bar"
    },
    "baz": {
      "value": null,
      "isSecret": true
    }
  }
}
```